# Binomial distribution with time-dependent probability

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

In the case of the binomial distribution, it is well known that given $N$ trials,  the expected number of trials to get a success is $Np$, where $p$ is the probability of success, and the variance is $Npq$, where $q = 1-p$.

My question is : **what if the probability is time-dependent how do these results change ?** Is there some formula for the average and standard deviation? Are there any references ?

Comment: Have a look at the Poisson Binomial distribution

Answer (score 1):

You can work out the maths by yourself : let $X_k$ be a Bernoulli trial with success probability $p_k$. Now let $S_n=X_1+...+X_n$. What you're looking for is $\mathbb{E}[S_n]$. It is given the same as in the usual case : $$\mathbb{E}[S_n]=\mathbb{E}[X_1]+...+\mathbb{E}[X_n]=p_1+...+p_n.$$

The Binomial Distribution is a special case where $p_1=...=p_n=p$, yielding $\mathbb{E}[X_n]=np$. The same goes for the variance, assuming all $X_k$ are independant : $$\mathbb{V}(S_n)=\mathbb{V}(X_1)+...+\mathbb{V}(X_n)=p_1(1-p_1)+...+p_n(1-p_n).$$

Once again, the Binomial Distribution is a special case, and the corresponding formula holds.

However, if you're interested in **non-independant** behaviour (*e.g.* if the probability $p_{k+1}$ depends on the result $X_k$), it gets a little more complicated. I suggest you take a look at [Conditional probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) first.

**Edit :** as suggested by `fGDu94`, I'll link the [Poisson Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution) as well for further documentation.

Comment: Thanks, that helps.